# How can I wait to electron while loading html

Tags: javascript, electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I have an electron app which loads an HTML file on opening. 
When I tried to wait for an element with `waitUntil` method from the opening page, Spectron tries to find that while page loading and it crashes my app and app staying at the blank page. How can I wait for loading of this HTML?

My application launch code is below :

```
async start() {
    try {
      await this.spectron.start();
      await this.focusOnWindow(0);
      return this._checkWindowReady();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }

 beforeEach(async function (){
            app = new SpectronApplication();
            common = new CommonActions();

            await app.start();
 })
```

Comment: can u use `webContents` events? [`'dom-ready'`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-dom-ready) for example

Comment: not yet i am now trying it now but it is electron's function, I need to handle this issue on spectron.

Comment: yes, I see that. I'm not familiar with spectron, just seen this in docs: "Spectron makes the entire Chromium and Electron APIs available to your tests." That's why I thought it's easy to access webContents

Comment: "Spectron makes the entire Chromium and Electron APIs available to your tests." but when you add some os level uı elements spectron can't handle it.(for example right click opening a menu but it is comes from os) I am not believing that anymore. I will try your answer thank you about it.

Comment: I’m not familiar with spectron, but in your example you spelled ‘beforeEach’ wrong. Could the typo be the problem?

Comment: I just wrote it manually not pasted it from code :) Now I am editing it to true.

Comment: Thank you guys for your supports we found solution and I shared it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution like below code :

Firstly when I call `app.start()` ,

`start()` function calls `_checkWindowReady()`

`_checkWindowReady` calls `waitFor()`

And finally `waitFor` calls `_callClientAPI()` and it looks for specific function and element.

```
 async start() {
    try {
      await this.spectron.start();
      await this.focusOnWindow(0);
      return this._checkWindowReady();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }

 _checkWindowReady() {
    return this.waitFor(this.spectron.client.getHTML, '[id="myApp.main.body"]');
  }

 waitFor(func, args) {
    return this._callClientAPI(func, args);
  }

 _callClientAPI(func, args) {
    let trial = 1;
    return new Promise(async(res, rej) => {
      while (true) {
        if (trial > this._pollTrials) {
          rej(`Could not retrieve the element in ${this._pollTrials * this._pollTimeout} seconds.`);
          break;
        }

        let result;
        try {
          result = await func.call(this.client, args, false);
        } catch (e) { }

        if (result && result !== '') {
          res(result);
          break;
        }

        await this.wait();
        trial++;
      }
    });
  }
```